# Dynamics CRM 365 - Using Virtual entities

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-sql-database, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Someone can explain to me if I can increase the Dynamics CRM performance if I implement some virtual entities with an external Database? ( I already know the limits of this entities) I have a Dynamics crm project with a bunch of records ( more than 20 000 000) and figured out if the performance with UI ( and advanced find .. ) will be increased with this "architecture".

There is someone out there with experience with virtual entities in V9.0?

Regards,

Comment: if implemented correctly the odata endpoint can be queried with $top and $max when paging.

Answer (score 0):

I implement server paging and it ok with my virtual entities (more than 1m rows)